# Where is the Java EE perspective in Eclipse?

Tags: java

Where is the Java EE perspective in Eclipse Indigo 4.2.2?

Comment: Are you sure you have downloaded the JEE edition, because you need this one in order to enable the JEE perspective.

Comment: Why the down-votes? It's a basic but legitimate question.

Answer (score 1):

in the eclipse window go to...

**Window**`->` **Open Perspective**`->` **Other**`->` **javaEE(default)**

and you're done.